# accessing class fields from GSP in Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

How can I access fields of classes from a GSP in Grails? For instance, the following:

```
geocoder.geocode({
      'address': 'london'
   },
```

I need to get the address programmatically after being inserted by the user. Something as the following:

```
geocoder.geocode({
      'address': ${search.city}
   },
```

where search is the class and city is the field.
Is there a way to do this?
Thanks

**UPDATE**

I tried this:
In the controller:

```
def map = {
    def searchInstance = Search.get(1)
    [locationList : Location.list(), search:searchInstance]
}
```

In the view:

```
function initialize() {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
      'address': ${search.city}
   }, 
   function(results, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

          var myMapOptions = {
                  zoom: 8,
                  center: results[0].geometry.location,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                    myMapOptions);

                <g:each in="${locationList}" status="i" var="location">     
                var point${location.id} = new google.maps.LatLng(${location.lat}, ${location.lng});
                var myMarkerOptions${location.id} = {
                      position: point${location.id}, 
                      map: map
                     };
                if(map.getCenter().distanceFrom(point${location.id}) < 500000)
                    var marker${location.id} = new google.maps.Marker(myMarkerOptions${location.id});   
            </g:each>

      }
   });
```

}

I can access from the view the Location list returned by the map closure, but I can not access the search instance. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `geocoder.geocode({ ... })` portion already inside a `${}` in the GSP?

Comment: No, it is in a javascript script but not inside ${}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you pass an instance of that class as a model from your controller to your view, you can access the fields just as you normally would.

```
Controller: searchController {
    def search = {
        def searchInstance = Search.get(1) //assuming this gets the search that you want
        [search:searchInstance] // return searchInstance to the view under the alias search
    }
}

Gsp: search.gsp {
    geocoder.geocode({
      'address': ${search.city}
   },
}
```

Comment: Your solution looks like exactly what I need, but it's not working for me. Perhaps because I need the city field, not in the search.gsp but in a map.gsp. I have an additional closure in the Controller called map which is what I use to call the map.gsp. It is giving the exception: Cannot get property 'city' on null object

Comment: It doesn't give any error afterall. But the view never show up. Please see the update of the question to check the code.

Comment: I found the error. I had to call the search instance inside quotes, like this: 'address':"${search.city}"

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just return the `search` variable as [part of your model in the controller](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.3%20Models%20and%20Views)?